# AngularJS directive dynamic model binding to view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am having following directive:

```
app.directive('renderPartial', function($compile) {
   return {
      restrict: "AE",
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
         var path = getPartial(attrs.module, attrs.file);
         //path = /abc/some_file.html
         scope[attrs.model] = path;
         var el = $compile('<div ng-include="attrs.model"></div>')(scope);
         element.html(el);
      }
   }
});
```

In my view:

```
<render-partial module="abc" file="some_file" model="some_model"></render-partial>
```

Now for some reason this is not working, no errors. But file is not getting rendered.

Plunkr for my problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/CkTE2pV4i5LvL60NEYfE

Comment: ping check my updated answer :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

According to plunker attached in the comment:-

You need to do couple of things

1) Use `var el = $compile('<div ng-include="'+attrs.model+'"></div>')(scope);`

2)  `element.append(el);` instead of plane HTML :-P

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y4ZQ2DshU1g6owxw4pAM?p=preview)

Comment: No, I want this to work: `var el = $compile('<div ng-include="scope[attrs.model]"></div>')(scope);`

Comment: I way saying put only value of attrs.model inside your ng-include don't include scop becuase it is a glue b/w view and logic.So, suppose attr.model has 'one' then scope[attrs.model] will turn to scope[one] which is equivaluent to scope.one and in view it will be only 'one'. You don't need scope word in front of it.

Comment: If I try this `var el = $compile('<div ng-include="attrs.model"></div>')(scope);` still its not working

Comment: @ntechi can you replicate it in fiddle or plunker ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it dynamic, like this:

```
myApp.directive('renderPartial', function($compile) {
   return {
      restrict: "AE",
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
         var path = 'test.html';
         scope.path = path;
         var el = $compile('<div ng-include="path"></div>')(scope);  
         element.append(el);
      }
   }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/12142/)

Comment: This will not work if I have multiple same directive calls with different files, cause the scope is not array